# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'string_column'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to count the delimiter from my CSV file using this piece of code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(path,sep=',')
df['comma_count'] = df.string_column.str.count(',')
print (df)
```

But I keep getting this error:
**'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'string_column'**.
Trying to iterate through my dataframe had no avail.

I am trying to achieve this:

```
     id    val      new  comma_count
     id    val      new          2
0     a    2.0    234.0          2
1     a    5.0    432.0          2
2     a    4.0    234.0          2
3     a    2.0  23423.0          2
4     a    9.0    324.0          2
5     a    7.0      NaN          1
6   NaN  234.0      NaN          1
7     a    6.0      NaN          1
8     4    NaN      NaN          0
```

My file:

```
id,val,new
a,2,234
a,5,432
a,4,234
a,2,23423
a,9,324
a,7
,234
a,6,
4
```

Comment: Waht is `print (df.columns)` ? Error means there is no column `string_column`

Comment: Index(['id', 'val', 'new'], dtype='object')
I am trying to count the delimiter over all columns (id, val and new)

Comment: well, you have 3 delimiters per row that are used to create your column with the `sep=','`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different separator with select first column and `count`:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(path,sep='|')
df['dot_count'] = df1.iloc[:, 0].str.count(',')
```

Comment: My output is not showing the count (It`s just 0 for all lines). Also, I want to count the delimiters in my header too.

Comment: @Oliveira - Can you add small data sample with exepected ouput to question?

Comment: @Oliveira - so need count `dot` ? Not comma? also why in first row are 2?

Comment: added a sample of my file. its comma. sorry

Comment: comma count still 0 though

Comment: @Oliveira - Not understand first row - header is mixed with data?

Comment: its the first row of my file